# jquery siblings removeclass

Tags: jquery

Toggleclass works perfectly but siblings dont. 

I miss something and the class "corrente" dont remove if i click in another button h1.

Structure code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.box").addClass(" invisivel");
    $("#menu a").click(function(){
        $(this).next("ul.box")
            .slideToggle("slow")
            .siblings("ul.box:visible")
            .slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children("h1")
            .toggleClass("corrente")
            .siblings("h1")
            .removeClass("corrente");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Html code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="">
        <h1 class="link-titulo">Oficina da África</h1>
    </a>
    <ul class="box">
        <li>xxx</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="">
        <h1 class="link-titulo">Calendário/Currículo</h1>
    </a>
    <ul class="box">
        <li>xxx</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).children("h1").toggleClass("corrente")
    .end().siblings("h1").removeClass("corrente");`

Comment: without relevant html we cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

After calling `.children()` you are now working with that new set of elements, so calling `.siblings()` then accesses the siblings *of* the children. You can use [`jQuery.fn.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to go back to the previous set:

```
$(this).children("h1").toggleClass("corrente")
.end() // <--
.siblings("h1").removeClass("corrente");
```

Comment: Think about: this is correct that a `h1` will have another `h1` as sibling.

Comment: But then the code would be very strange: `.children('h1')` already has all "h1" elements of that parent, `.siblings('h1')` would result in a set of exactly the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this and if possible add ur html code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("ul.box").addClass(" invisivel");
$('#menu a').each(function() {
 $(this).click(function() { 
    $(this).next("ul.box").slideToggle("slow")
    .siblings("ul.box:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children("h1").toggleClass("corrente")
    .siblings("h1").removeClass("corrente");
    return false;
});

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
.siblings("h1").removeClass("corrente");
```

with

```
.next("h1").removeClass("corrente");
```